# Is there a specific way you need to call a function in a console on "vs studio" in python language

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

Every time a call the function in the "vs studio" terminal it always gives me this error.

```
PS C:\Users\Firstname\python> telephonebook()  //the function i try to call is "telephonebook()" in python
At line:1 char:12
+ telephonebook()
+            ~
An expression was expected after '('.
    + CategoryInfo          : ParserError: (:) [], ParentContainsErrorRecordException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ExpectedExpression
```

the thing is, i only get this error in the "vs studio" editor. If i call the function in IDLE python, it works just fine. where the way the navigate in my telephonebook is working as expected.

is there a specific way to call a function in "vs studio" terminal?

Comment: You typed the command into a PowerShell terminal, not a Python interpreter.

Comment: Right.  VSCode expects you to run the script.  Include `print(telephonebook())` as the last line and run it.

Comment: Thanks @TimRoberts, i can run the code now. Is there a way to run the function like in IDLE python, Where you just call the function in the terminal instead? or do you have to use the code "print(telephonebook())" to call the function.

Comment: Not in VSCode.  It just has a different philosophy, focused on editing files.  IDLE is very tightly integrated with Python itself.

Comment: @jasonharper , is there a tutorial site for choosing python shell as your terminal?